# ./aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfow.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, anaconda, qemu

I wanted to run `qemu` on the terminal but I got this error:

```bash
--> Start qemu version:
./aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfow.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Start glibc test qemu option.
./aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfow.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any package I should install?

---

#### System Details

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04LTS,
- Python: Anaconda distribution (`/home/user/anaconda3`)

Comment: Needs to be edited

Comment: Please add details on how you installed and invoke the command (show the actual command). I don't know `qemu`, but usually dynamic library issues come from mixing channels. Try creating a fresh environment and prioritizing the channel from which `qemu` comes.

Comment: try execute: `sudo apt install libtinfo-dev`

Comment: Im not really sure whats in the installation script, as It is my school project, but I'm guess is related to the python variable environment, the default folder should be /usr/bin/python, and not /home/user/anaconda3, thank you for the help, I will probably uninstall anaconda or set the python path

Comment: I've uninstall anaconda, which interfere the environment path of python, and reinstall qemu and it works! Thank for helping me out. I guess, i've to edit the installation script file of qemu to link to the dynamic library path, before installing qemu. Or I can edit .bashrc file to make /usr/bin/python the default environment path. Linux is a little new to me